# How to send motion data into blender using python API?

Tags: python, bvh

I want to continuously send motion data in the blender using python API. The data itself is the same as the 'MOTION' section in .bvh format. How am I suppose to transform this data to apply it in the same way .bvh does to do it in real-time myself? It seems like I'm missing some kind of transformation of rotation angles in here.

The end of my sample .bvh file:

```
.....................................
    JOINT chest
    {
      OFFSET 80 0 0
      CHANNELS 3 Zrotation Xrotation Yrotation
    }
MOTION
Frames: 1
Frame Time: 10
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 40 60
```

The last three numbers (20 40 60) are rotation values of chest JOINT.

I'm importing this file and depending what rotation mode I use I'm getting the angle numbers inside the Blender (rotation_euler or rotation_quaternion). The problem is that I can't get my head around these angle values. As an exmaple of transformation:

Input in degrees from .bvh file: 20 40 60

Output in Blender importing .bvh as Quaternion: (0.9396926164627075, 0, 0, 0.3420201539993286)

What kind of transformation have done that?